# How do I git pull a dev branch?

Tags: version-control

I'm trying to switch to the dev version of Views. Repository [instructions](http://drupal.org/project/views/git-instructions) worked and I was able to `git clone` Views.

However, listing the available branches with `git branch -a` only shows `* 7.x-3.x`
.

And trying to add a "dev" branch with pull returns an error:

```
$ git pull origin 7.x-3.x
From http://git.drupal.org/project/views
 * branch            7.x-3.x    -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
$ git pull origin 7.x-3.x-dev
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref 7.x-3.x-dev
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you actually read the answer before editing your question?

Comment: @Chapabu, The purpose of these edits were to make the question more readable--for future readers--as I tried several different commands and the previous version read strange. The question is the same and the answer remains relevant. What is your concern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I do

```
git clone --recursive --branch 7.x-3.x http://git.drupal.org/project/views.git
```

and then

```
git branch -r
```

I get

```
origin/4.6.x-1.x  
origin/4.7.x-1.x  
origin/5.x-1.x  
origin/6.x-2.11-security  
origin/6.x-2.x  
origin/6.x-3.x  
origin/7.x-3.x  
origin/8.x-3.x  
origin/HEAD -> origin/7.x-3.x  
origin/d7v3ui  
origin/master
```

I believe you need the recursive flag to get all remotes. Not sure if you did that, but a quick git fetch will update your list of remotes.

```
git pull origin 7.x-3.x-dev
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref 7.x-3.x-dev
Unexpected end of command stream
```

I think this is just due to the naming conventions, current dev is HEAD afaik.

```
git pull origin 7.x-3.x
From http://git.drupal.org/project/views
 * branch            7.x-3.x    -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

I believe that any branch (not tag) can be considered 'dev' for that drupal version.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for "...this is just due to the naming conventions, current dev is HEAD..."

Comment: Any Drupal development snapshot is created from a git branch. On Drupal.org git branch names never include the -dev part.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not a Git expert, but as I understand it all of the releases of the dev branch listed on the project page are made directly to the 7.x-3.x branch.  Of course you're free to create your own branches locally for your own needs, but the `master`-like branch, which includes all of the releases pushed to drupal.org, is always going to be that 7.x-3.x branch.

If you want to switch to one of the tagged releases, use `git tag` to get a list of all the releases.  Then, to check out the `7.x-3.1` release (for example), use `git co 7.x-3.1`.

If you intend to edit the code for this release, you can then create a new branch (as Git explains) by using `git checkout -b mycustombranch`.

Comment: +1 for the answer, although to clarify: If maintainers are using git on Drupal.org properly there should never be a master branch - there should only be version specific branches.

Comment: @Chapabu Thanks for the clarification!  I updated my answer.

Comment: I now remember why I hesitated accepting the answer! Today, when I attempted to add a patch from last month, `$git apply` said the patch doesn't apply, and yet the patch is very recent. And just to be certain, I grep'd the file for the change line and its not in the latest release `7.x-2.0-beta`. Using `$git tag` I get the following 7.x releases: `7.x-2.0`, `7.x-2.0-beta1` but you'll see there is no 7.x-2.x-dev. So my original question is really unanswered. Either 'dev' is not in the repository, or it is--in which case why does the new patch not apply?

Comment: The dev branch is the 3.x branch.  HEAD will always be the latest dev release; each individual dev release will not usually be tagged.  As for why the patch doesn't apply, that's specific to the patch you're trying to apply.  However, the date or how recent the patch is doesn't matter-- it's only whether the code is changed or not.  Almost all patches on drupal.org will specify to which version of a module/core they apply.

Comment: Ok. Just to keep it simple, let's use the new example (which is the [Draggableviews](http://drupal.org/project/draggableviews) module) instead of the older Views example. Then in this example 7.x-2.0-beta1 is _latest version_ and _commonly understood as the dev release_? and I navigate to the latest with `$git checkout master`?

Comment: Draggableviews has a 2.0 release, so I'm not sure where you got beta1.  If you follow the instructions here this should give you a working copy: http://drupal.org/node/283087/git-instructions/7.x-2.x  However, it sounds like you are very confused about Git.  I would read a Git tutorial or two first; it will definitely pay off in saving you time later.

Comment: I would like to accept your answer. If you will edit it to reflect the relationship of dev branch to the cloned git repository I think you have it. No where on the page you linked to is this specific info, yet clearly on the main page, in this case [Draggableviews](http://drupal.org/project/draggableviews) is the "Development releases" _table_ making this info, if not instructionally clear, at least organizationally clear. I would hazard the guess this is why the question has received up points.

Answer (score 3):

The way to pull the repository for the 7.x-3.x branch of the Views module (i.e. the development snapshot 7.x-3.x-dev for the Views module) from Drupal.org for the first time is executing the following command:

```
git pull git clone --recursive --branch 7.x-3.x http://git.drupal.org/project/views.git
```

After that, if you need to keep the local repository for the Views module updated, you should execute the following commands:

```
cd views
```

```
git reset --hard
```

```
git pull origin 7.x-3.x
```

To make it clear: A Drupal development snapshot is created from a git branch, while a Drupal release is created from a git tag. The name of the git branch is the name of the Drupal development snapshot without the -dev part. In your case the development snapshot is 7.x-3.x-dev, and the git branch is 7.x-3.x.
Furthermore, the git tag used to create a Drupal release must follow a specific schema. Tags similar to 7.x-3.0 (or 7.x-3.1-beta3) are for the 7.x-3 version of a module, and its development snapshot is named 7.x-3.x-dev. On Drupal.org, you cannot create a Drupal release from a git tag similar to beta-release, or a Drupal snapshot from a git branch similar to test-branch.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: As pointed out, the **question** was "How do I git pull a dev branch" which has been partially demonstrated in the other answers. Yet, a key second part of any answer must include a translation of the Drupal -dev naming convention. Simply because it does not appear using the commands `$git branch` or `$git tag` while `-dev` clearly is evident in the "Development releases" table on a module's main page. This is my attempt to clarify this with a reasoned, but in no sense authoritative, definition:

There is a sense **-dev** is equivalent to **rough draft** in the familiar metaphor of writing. An article describes setting up "your own Git repository viewer" on a local repository (for developers who prefer to not host in *the cloud*),

> "You can choose either the latest stable version or the master version, but keep in mind the master version may have bugs since developers are actively working on it." [PHPMaster](http://phpmaster.com/installing-gitlist-for-local-repos/)

Now we have a definitive statement describing a convention for *active development* on the "master version". And here is the principal issue I've been working on in this post: relating a convention (developer convention, programming best practice, or *The Drupal Way*) to the operation and use of the git application.

Now, you'll have to bear with me for a moment as I digress. In my novice git-ucation, I wasn't sure if "master" was also a naming convention of developers or built into the git application itself. And here I turned to a site search at the maintainers site, git-scm.com, to find this gem:

> "In the default case that is automatically written by a `git remote add` command, Git fetches all the references under refs/heads/ on the server and writes them to refs/remotes/origin/ locally. So, if there is a master branch on the server, you can access the log of that branch locally..." [git-scm](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-The-Refspec)

*if there is a master branch*? That does not suggest "every" git repository has a "master". Fortunately this mystery was quickly solved by creating my own test repository and a subsequent search at Stackoverflow confirms this is technically true, a new git repository without *any* commits does not have a *master* branch:

> "Now, the reason you wouldn't have a master branch even after doing a git init is that there are no commits: when you create your first commit, you will then have a master branch." [stackoverflow: "fatal: Not a valid object name: 'master'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162271/fatal-not-a-valid-object-name-master)

Its a strange example to find at the maintainers site, adding a remote repository without any commits, but in the Land of Oz customization to the *nth* degree is a known hazzard.

Now, returning the helpful advise I've received to this point. Kiamlaluno points out,

> "A Drupal development snapshot is created from a git branch, while a Drupal release is created from a git tag." Instead of git tag try with git branch."

And yet, still won't say what I'm about to say. Now its finally possible to understand **the `-dev` branch in Drupal as the "development snapshot" created from the "master" branch of the git branch hosted at Drupal.org.** The `-dev` branch label is not present in the branch command output *unless you put it there yourself* in your local cloned repository. This I've also tested, recently, because I found it useful to label my current working brach different than the remote master branch of the same name.

I chose to use the git versions and use git to make my own `-dev` branch of a few modules to troubleshoot the interaction of Views and Draggableviews modules, because. as Kiamlaluno points out, the tar and gzip files in the "Development releases" table are snapshots. Thus, by reason they are always older than the master branch.

---

In another curious event, here is a definition of snapshot from a Wikipedia Disambiguation Page,

> Snapshot: "A view of a source code repository as it was at a particular time for the purpose of [revision control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) in software development." [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapshot)

Its ironic to find this definition for "source code repository" not in an wiki-article, or at wiktionary, but tucked away in a disambiguation page. Not ironic because the definition should be tucked away in a remote location, rather this brings to mind a printing term [widow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widow_%28typesetting%29), which does have its own wiki-article page and [wictionary entry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/widow#English), unlike git's 'master branch', or Drupal's '-dev branch' (at the time of this missive).

Comment: Blimey, looks like you've had a long day's reading :) Thanks for sharing, this is really useful info